# How to repaint QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I have **QTreeWidget**. In which I'm adding new column dynamically on button click event using **setHeaderLabels**. This API add new column in `TreeWidget` but column is not visible in current `TreeWidget` area. It adds a scroll bar in `TreeWidget`. Therefore to view newly added column user has to scroll the tree.
This my scenario but I don't want to scroll. I have used update() function even though its not showing new column. Is there any way to repaint the widget.
Thank you !

Comment: Maybe you need to add items for new column too?

Comment: i am adding text to new column using old TreeItems.

Comment: You need to show some code so people can understand what's wrong.

Comment: Try setting `tv->header()->setStretchLastSection(false)` on init and call `tv->resizeColumnToContents(int col)`each time you're adding a column

Comment: @Robert your solution works for me just add your solution in answer so that i can upvote you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call

```
treeWidget->header()->setStretchLastSection(false);
```

at the initialization and

```
treeWidget->resizeColumnToContent(column);
```

each time your adding a column.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
resizeColumnToContents(int col)
```

will help you. (You should call it every time after adding new column)

Btw, don't forget to call

```
header()->setStretchLastSection(false)
```

on initialization of **TreeView**